# How to find Node.js Socket.io connection address with SSL?

Tags: node.js, laravel, ssl, socket.io, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel PHP application running on a Forge server. There are multiple Nginx sites on the server. I am attempting to set up a Socket.io connection. I had this running previously with HTTP, but with SSL is breaks.

To start, I made a new site in forge (`socket.mydomain.com`) and use `Forever` to run the Node.js script. I know the script is running as it is receiving events and outputting them in the console - I just can't connect on the front end.

My socket.io script is:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs =    require('fs');

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/socket.example.com/54082/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/socket.example.com/54082/server.crt')
};

var app = https.createServer(options);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('connected');

});

app.listen(3000);
```

The code I am using on the front end is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://socket.example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var io = io('https://socket.example.com', {secure: true});

....
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work with SSL? Like, what should the address/port be? How do I start this with Forever on the correct port? And should my Nginx set up have something specific?

Many many thanks, this has been an issue for ages....

Comment: any update? were you able to get this working? I'm having the same issue. Many thanks!

Comment: @kevnk Unfortunately no! I ended up giving up and using [Pusher](http://pusher.com). It is free up to 200,000 messages per day, which is more than enough for me. It took about 10 minutes to set up...

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var io = io('https://socket.example.com', {secure: true});
```

to

```
var io = io('https://socket.example.com:3000', {secure: true});
```

as your node app is listening on port 3000

Comment: Interesting. I tried this but it times out after around 30 seconds of trying to load...

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup that ended up working for me:

**First**, I put my node server on the forge server (which is nice b/c all the code is in the same repository)

**Second**, I did a proxy pass so `https://example.com/sockets` would go to `http://MY_PRIVATE_IP:8080`

*nginx config:*

```
location /socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://MY_PRIVATE_IP:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

**Third**, (the part I couldn't figure out for a day and a half) doing a proxy pass makes the socket.io [namespaced](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/). So then my node server scripts looked like this:

*server.js:*

```
var http = require('http')
var server = http.Server();

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var nsp = io.of('/socket/:8080');
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channel');

redis.on('message', function(channel, data){
  message = JSON.parse(data);
  nsp.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
})

server.listen(8080, process.env.SOCKET_PRIVATE_HOST, function(){
  console.log('node server running')
})
```